# Get image from clipboard and save it to the server from client browser chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [this tutorial](http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/), it works in chrome, it shows me an image as a div background image

now I want to save that image on the server side in specific folder... mine sample code 
just copy and save it in .html and open with chrome ... and press printscreen button of keyboard and click on this page and press Ctrl+V
you will see the image... now I want that image to save on server side in a specific folder

My code

```
            <html lang="en-US">

            <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
            <title>HTML5 JavaScript Pasting Image Data in Chrome   </title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://strd6.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css" />
            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://strd6.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>

            </head>

            <body  >
            <div id="page" style="height:1000px">

             <script>

            (function() {
              (function($) {
                var defaults;
                $.event.fix = (function(originalFix) {
                  return function(event) {
                    event = originalFix.apply(this, arguments);
                    if (event.type.indexOf('copy') === 0 || event.type.indexOf('paste') === 0) {
                      event.clipboardData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
                    }
                    return event;
                  };
                })($.event.fix);
                defaults = {
                  callback: $.noop,
                  matchType: /image.*/
                };
                return $.fn.pasteImageReader = function(options) {
                  if (typeof options === "function") {
                    options = {
                      callback: options
                    };
                  }
                  options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                  return this.each(function() {
                    var $this, element;
                    element = this;
                    $this = $(this);
                    return $this.bind('paste', function(event) {
                      var clipboardData, found;
                      found = false;
                      clipboardData = event.clipboardData;
                      return Array.prototype.forEach.call(clipboardData.types, function(type, i) {
                        var file, reader;
                        if (found) {
                          return;
                        }
                        if (type.match(options.matchType) || clipboardData.items[i].type.match(options.matchType)) {
                          file = clipboardData.items[i].getAsFile();
                          reader = new FileReader();
                          reader.onload = function(evt) {
                            return options.callback.call(element, {
                              dataURL: evt.target.result,
                              event: evt,
                              file: file,
                              name: file.name
                            });
                          };
                          reader.readAsDataURL(file);

                          return found = true;
                        }
                      });
                    });
                  });
                };
              })(jQuery);
            }).call(this);
            jQuery("html").pasteImageReader(function(results) {
              var dataURL, filename;
              filename = results.filename, dataURL = results.dataURL;


              return jQuery("#page").css({
                backgroundImage: "url(" + dataURL + ")",
                backgroundRepeat: "repeat"
              });
            });
            </script> 


            </div> 


            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: You will need a different - server side - language to do that. Suggestions are PHP, Perl or Java (not Javascript!)

Comment: yes off course  dear i am using java as server side language .... but i am unable to get that on server .... give suggestion how i take it to server

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to send the data to the server, probably with an Ajax POST request. The data can be extracted from dataURL, it's a base64 encoded image with some metadata at the front.

Answer (score 0):

yesterday i am facing that problem now i solve that in Firefox ......

sample code 
index.jsp

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  >


    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= request.getContextPath()%>" + "/ImageCreator",
            data: {html: $('#mydiv').find("img").attr('src')},
            success: function() {
                alert("Image Successfully Uploaded,Now Go Back And Click Submit");
                 window.close();
                 window.close();
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error Occurred  While Uploading Image");
            }
        });
    });

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <h2>Press Keyboard "Print Screen key" Than Click in the Colored Area and Press Control+V then Click  Upload Button</h2>
      <!--  <div onclick="createDiv()"> Click Here!</div> 
    <div onclick="subb();"> Click Value!</div> -->
      <Button href="#" id="submit" >Upload</button>
      <div contenteditable="" id="mydiv" style=" height: 700px;background-color: #CCCCCC;"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

in the it send the ajex request to the servlet   name /ImageCreator

that is the code of servlet

```
        import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.PrintWriter;
        import java.text.DateFormat;
        import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
        import java.util.Date;
        import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
        import javax.mail.Session;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
        import util.ImageUtils;

        /**
         *
         * @author Zeeshan Akhter
         */
        public class ImageCreator extends HttpServlet {

            protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                BufferedImage newImg;
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                String minedata = request.getParameter("html");
              //  System.out.println("minedata" + minedata);
                newImg = ImageUtils.decodeToImage(minedata.replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""));

                String date = "";
                Date date1 = new Date();
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyhhmmss");
                date = formatter.format(date1);
                //  File FilePathsdd = new File(FilePaths);
                //  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,application.getRealPath(request.getContextPath()+"/js/") );
                File dateFolder = new File(((String) session.getAttribute("imagePath")) + "/js/" + date);
                if (!dateFolder.exists()) {
                    dateFolder.mkdir();
                    dateFolder.setExecutable(true);
                    dateFolder.setReadable(true);
                    dateFolder.setWritable(true);
                }
                String path = dateFolder.getAbsolutePath();
                while ((path.contains("\\"))) {
                    System.out.println("\nPath1=" + path);
                    path = (path.replace("\\", "/"));
                    System.out.println("\nPath2=" + path);
                }
                File Save = new File(path + "/ForexImage.png");
                System.out.println("ImagePath=" + Save.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/"));
                session.setAttribute("createdFilePath", Save.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/"));
                ImageIO.write(newImg, "png", Save);

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the class util.ImageUtils

```
package util;



/**
 *
 * @author ZeeshanAakhter
 *http://latest-tutorial.com
 *http://zeeshanakhter.com
 */
import java.io.IOException;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageUtils {

    /**
     * Decode string to image
     *
     * @param imageString The string to decode
     * @return decoded image
     */
    public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {

        BufferedImage image = null;
        byte[] imageByte;
        try {
            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
            image = ImageIO.read(bis);
            bis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }

    /**
     * Encode image to string
     *
     * @param image The image to encode
     * @param type jpeg, bmp, ...
     * @return encoded string
     */
    public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {
        String imageString = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
            byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();

            BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);

            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageString;
    }
}
```